# how to parse a row in a csv file and store it in different dataframes on basis of some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am parsing a csv file(charges.csv), which contains some invalid entries. I would like to read the csv file and keep valid entries in one dataframe(charges) and invalid ones in other(invalid). How can I do that?

I am not getting any ideas as of now, would like to hear out the some suggestions.

Comment: Instead of using `pd.read_csv()`, loop through the CSV file with the `csv` module. In your loop you can append to the appropriate df based on the condition.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is hard.  You do exactly what you wrote in your paragraph.  You have practically designed the program in that paragraph.  Just build up the rows as two list-of-lists, and convert to pandas at the end.

Comment: Libraries do have their own philosophias. Pandas has a strong expectation for input data to be either valid or garbage as a whole. If you can have both valid and invalid data in the same file, then you have to pre-process it before feeding Pandas with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you could mention the exact conditions for determining a valid or invalid row. This way, I can provide a more in-depth explanation. However, I can give you an example to help you better understand the concept. Let's assume you have a CSV file with 8 rows and three columns. If any row has at least one entry with a NaN value, it is considered invalid; otherwise, it is valid. With this condition in mind, you can use the provided code to separate the dataframe. You only have to modify the condition according to your desired conditions.

**test.csv**

```
name,age,amount
John Doe,30,1000
Jane Smith,25,750
Mike Johnson,40,1200
Anna Lee,35,NaN
Tom Brown,40,900
David Lee,34,1500
Sarah Williams,28,NaN
Alex Turner,NaN,800
```

**Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/content/test.csv')

def is_valid(row):
    # Assuming the row is valid if there are no NaN values in any column
    return not row.isnull().any()

valid_mask = df.apply(is_valid, axis=1)
valid_df = df[valid_mask]
invalid_df = df[~valid_mask]

print("Valid Entries:")
print(valid_df)

print("\nInvalid Entries:")
print(invalid_df)
```

**Output:**

```
Valid Entries:
           name   age  amount
0      John Doe  30.0  1000.0
1    Jane Smith  25.0   750.0
2  Mike Johnson  40.0  1200.0
4     Tom Brown  40.0   900.0
5     David Lee  34.0  1500.0

Invalid Entries:
             name   age  amount
3        Anna Lee  35.0     NaN
6  Sarah Williams  28.0     NaN
7     Alex Turner   NaN   800.0
```

Comment: I need to validate multiple conditions, one of which is to check if all the mandatory columns in the data frame are non-Null. If a column contains Null entries in any of the mandatory columns, then it is considered an invalid entry.

Comment: @SanketKale You can use the above code for the mentioned condition.